# What is the C# function that gives the same result as FoxPro Week(date, 2, 2)?

Tags: c#, foxpro

How to get week date in C# with identical result as FoxPro function `Week(date, 2, 2)`?

`GetWeekOfYear` is not giving the same results no matter which `CalendarWeekRule` is used.

Comment: How about you tell us what Foxpro's Week() function is supposed to do, what output you're expecting to get, and what `GetWeekOfYear` actually returns?

Comment: Sorry, no native function in C#, it will have to be converted to C# directly.  Do you need help on that conversion?

Comment: Well, if that funtion already exists on the net, it would be helpfull, otherwise, I will have to make it. thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not enough to just change the CalendarWeekRule, you also need to change the DayOfWeek.

In VFP, Week(date, 2, 2) specifies Monday as the FirstDayOfWeek.

Try this:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

Edit: 
check this out: [iso 8601 week of year in .net](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2006/01/24/iso-8601-week-of-year-format-in-microsoft-net.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The **Week** class of the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) includes support for the ISO 8601 week format:

```
public void CalendarWeekSample()
{
  DateTime testDate = new DateTime( 2007, 12, 31 );

  // .NET calendar week
  TimeCalendar calendar = new TimeCalendar();
  Console.WriteLine( "Calendar Week of {0}: {1}", testDate.ToShortDateString(),
                     new Week( testDate, calendar ).WeekOfYear );
  // > Calendar Week of 31.12.2007: 53

  // ISO 8601 calendar week
  TimeCalendar calendarIso8601 = new TimeCalendar(
    new TimeCalendarConfig { YearWeekType = YearWeekType.Iso8601 } );
  Console.WriteLine( "ISO 8601 Week of {0}: {1}", testDate.ToShortDateString(),
                     new Week( testDate, calendarIso8601 ).WeekOfYear );
  // > ISO 8601 Week of 31.12.2007: 1
} // CalendarWeekSample
```